# .htaccess redirecting based on User agent

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I am not great at writing regex's for .htaccess redirection but I managed to write this for redirecting basedon useragent.. My useragent String will contain a custom string at the end.. Let's just call this **ABC**.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^.*ABC$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1?&mode=test&app=true  [R=301,L]
```

However, though I am pretty sure that the user-agent request header contains the string. I cannot manage to get it redirected even to a different domain. Pretty sure both the lines are wrong.. the first by maybe 10% and the second by a 50%.

Can someone help me understand how to fix this?

*Additional Data*
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0 ABC"

Comment: what do you plan to accomplish with line 2? What is the URL you want to direct to?

Comment: The same url the user typed in but with the parameters ?mode=test&app=true

Comment: What URL did you use to test this rule?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if this works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ABC [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1?mode=test&app=true [L]
```

If you want the query string to also show along with the URL in the address bar then change `[L]` to `[R=301,L]`

Comment: Does't work... The problem is the rewriteCond ... It contains the normal browser string along with the prefix ABC .. refer to my original post for the usr agent String..

Comment: I understand that. That should work for ABC, Try adding the NC to the end as in my update. Are you sure you string has that ABC in it?